# Eclemma on Eclipse Neon (I can't find icon on toolbar)

Tags: eclipse, eclemma

[image]

I installed Eclemma on Eclipse Neon and the guide says I should be able to find an icon on the toolbar like above. However, I cannot find it and I searched online about this problem and saw some people having trouble with it. But I haven't found a solution to it..

I uninstalled and re-installed Eclemma but I still can't find the icon.

Comment: If you right-click on a unit test in the package/project explorer, or in the editor view for the test, you should have "Run as" and "Debug As" menus, and if you properly installed EclEmma, you should also have "Coverage As". If you don't see the icon, and you don't see the menu, I would have to assume that you didn't actually install it.

Comment: Hi @DavidM.Karr , thanks for comment. I saw "Coverage as" and when I run "Coverage as", it just created the icon on the toolbar. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve just had the same problem and a web search led me to this page. If you are using Windows 7 and Eclipse Neon, I found I could get the coverage button to appear (and work) if I:

1. Run Eclipse as administrator (right click and look for the menu item)
2. Install Eclemma as normal.
3. If prompted to restart Eclipse, click on “no”.
4. Manually close Eclipse
5. Run Eclipse again as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

1. From eclipse open Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective
2. Go to "Action Set Availability" tab
3. In the "Available action sets" pane check "Java Code Coverage" checkbox
4. Click Ok

Answer (score 0):

Use the keys CTRL + SHFT + F11! It worked on my windows 10.